# document.onclick not working on "Samsung Galaxy S" when clicking on dropdown(HTML Select Tag)

Tags: javascript, android, html

## I face an issue in Samsung Galaxy S device.

- when i click on drop down(HTML Select Tag) then **document.onclick**
  function does not fire. i don't know why this happen if anyone know
  any idea how to solve this then please suggest me

Thanks in advance

[image: Real Time problem snapshot]

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did you found any solution?